# Vue2 Reference method in data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue2  this seems to be break:

```js
<template>
  <v-list v-model="itemSelected">
    <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" @click="item.onClick"
      >item.label</v-list-item>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'myTestComponent'
  data: () => ({
    itemSelected,
    items: [
      { label: 'Logout', onClick: this.onLogoutClick },
      { label: 'Settings', onClick: this.onSettingsClick },
      { label: 'Profile', onClick: this.onProfileClick },
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    onLogoutClick() {
      console.log('LogoutClick')
    },
    onSettingsClick() {
      console.log('SettingsClick')
    },
    onProfileClick() {
      console.log('ProfileClick')
    },
  },
</script>
```

The error is that `onLogoutClick` is a null reference.  This seems to indicate to me that the `data` property is created before the `methods` property.

Is there a way around this?  Perhaps to pass the method names as a string and convert that reference to a method name at call time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass vue instance to data function, and call methods in `onClick` property :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: (vi) => ({
    itemSelected: null,
    items: [
      { label: 'Logout', onClick: vi.onLogoutClick },
      { label: 'Settings', onClick: vi.onSettingsClick },
      { label: 'Profile', onClick: vi.onProfileClick },
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    onLogoutClick() {
      console.log('LogoutClick')
    },
    onSettingsClick() {
      console.log('SettingsClick')
    },
    onProfileClick() {
      console.log('ProfileClick')
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-list v-model="itemSelected">
    <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" @click="item.onClick"
      >{{item.label}}</v-list-item>
      </v-list>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: hmm, confirmed.  Wonder why `this` isn't loaded but we we can pass the instance to the function as `vi`.